# how to get pixel movement while doing Fling?

Tags: android, touch-event, onfling

my application requires very precise measurements of movement. not very precise but close to it, I would like if the user has their finger on the screen and moves left or right ward lets suppose upto 100 pixels, I can track it.

```
 class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {

                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    //increament in image index & showImage()
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    //decrement in image index & showImage()
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

actually i have animation frames and on touch event i want to move those images quickly so that user could be able to see its 3d view in a smooth way and it is only possible when i have pixel to pixel track.

any one guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the gestureListener is the way to go.  I was able to use OnTouchEvent to keep track at the level you need:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // capture start position from event
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // do something interactively
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // check distance between start and end postions and do something
        break;
    }
    return true; // return true if you handle event otherwise return false!
}
```

There are many other action events to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE`, `SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH` or `SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY`?
You can declare them as such:

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 200;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
```

You can change the numeric values to your liking.